# trouble plotting function

Tags: python

Im trying to write a function, and then plot it. I am new to python and am having some trouble. I have to be missing information, just not sure where. Can anyone help?

```
xv= arange(-4,5,1)  
def f(x):
    if (x<0):
        return log(x)
    elif (0<=x<2):
        return (-x)
    elif (2<x):
        return x**2/(3-x)

xv= arange(-4,5,1)
y1= log(x)
y2= (-x)
y3= x**2/3-x

fig1=figure()
plot(xv,y1,y2,y3)
show()
```

Comment: You need to explain specifically what the problem is.  Does it raise an error?  If so, what error?  Does it not do what you want?  If so, what do you want, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Sorry, well for the first part when I defined the function. I dont have any sntax errors, but its also not returning anything. Im looking for numbers to be returned from the if statements and the three equations. So am I missing something in the first part of the problem?

Comment: you need to call the function to get something back ...

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to understand. For a start, your variables `y1`,`y2` and `y3` are using `x` as input, not `xv` which appears to be the abscissae you set up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-4, 5, 1)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

In your example, it looks like you are also attempting to take `log(x)`? If this is the case, remember that, mathematically, `log(x)` is complex if `x < 0`.

Hope this helps.